# In java i want to split the string and put it as key value pair

Tags: split, keyvaluepair

below is my string

status=OK;entries[url=http://www.krak.dk/53504900/s%C3%B8g.cs;datasource=KRAK_YELLOW_DATA;matchstring=hitlist;url=http://www.krak.dk/53504900/s%C3%B8g.cs;datasource=KRAK_YELLOW_DATA;matchstring=hit-list;]

i want to make the above string as key value pair like below

status = OK
entries=url=http://www.krak.dk/53504900/s%C3%B8g.cs;datasource=KRAK_YELLOW_DATA;matchstring=hitlist;url=http://www.krak.dk/53504900/s%C3%B8g.cs;datasource=KRAK_YELLOW_DATA;matchstring=hit-list

Answer (score 1):

you can use split method in java. Below is the link: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm